# Append div or span to a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to "attach" a `div` to a dropdown list. Is that possible?

I require something like this:

[image]

To be clear, I don't need to add `div` into the proper dropdownlist controller. I just need to attach.

What I've tried so far and not working:

---

**HTML**:

```
<select id="platypusDropDown">
    <option value="duckbill">duckbill</option>
    <option value="duckbillPlatypus">duckbillPlatypus</option>
    <option value="Platypus">Platypus</option>
    <option value="Platypi">Platypi</option>
</select>

<div id="addCategory">
    <input id="categoryInput" type="text" /> <br/>
    <input id="categoryInputAddBtn" type="button" value="Add new" />
</div>
```

---

**JS**:

```
$('#platypusDropDown').click(function () {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('addCategory');
    this.append(myDiv); 
});
```

Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: there must be some `css` role to clearly append and show hide plays

Comment: Change your js line `this.append(myDiv)` to `$(myDiv).after($(this))`. Or instead of `.after()`, you could try `.insertAfter()` :)

Comment: Does this fiddle satisfy ur requirement? http://jsfiddle.net/8FkA4/58/  GIVEN by SlyBeaver?

Comment: Why are asking something which is NOT Possible and VALID in HTML Markup ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think so, what you are trying to achieve is possible using select dropdown.What here, i will do is modify my HTML Code and use css style.

```
  <style type="text/css">
    ul{ list-style: none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0; }
  </style>
```

Here is my HTML Code: Instead of dropdown, i am using here ul li listing element.

```
 <div class="select-wrapper">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="slideDropDown">Select Dropdown</a>
   <ul id="platypusDropDown" style="display:none;">
    <li rel="duckbill">duckbill</li>
    <li rel="duckbillPlatypus">duckbillPlatypus</li>
    <li rel="Platypus">Platypus</li>
    <li rel="Platypi">Platypi</li>
   </ul>
 </div>

  <div class="wrapper" style="display:none;">
   <div id="addCategory">
     <input id="categoryInput" type="text" /> <br/>
     <input id="categoryInputAddBtn" type="button" value="Add new" />
   </div>
  </div>


  Here is my JS code:

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var flg = 0;
        $('.select-wrapper').click(function(){
                flg++;
                if(flg == 1){
                    $this_html = jQuery('.wrapper').html();
                    $("#platypusDropDown").append("<li>"+$this_html+"</li>");
                }

                $("#platypusDropDown").slideToggle();
        });
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Only problem is that the dropdown closes itself when the input field is selected.

Comment: Was going to answer the same kind of solution using a fake dropdown +1 . As @Daniel stated, the input can't be selected but the OP didn't say exaclty when it should close... (on otpion select or when input is entered)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add DIV to selectBlock. But you can add option into select:

```
$('#platypusDropDown').click(function () {
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('addCategory');
    $(this).after(myDiv); 
});
```

Comment: this will append the `div` on every `click` event, not good so far

Comment: Oh, sorry. replace `.append(...)` to `.after(myDiv)`

Comment: I'll try to fix my answer. See them again.

Answer (score 1):

LEAVE jQuery Part . This is not possible by setting HTML static markup WITH select Containing DIV . SO IT IS NOT POSSIBLE . u may use markup but , still It wil hide in browser even though u can see in Firebug , div is attached to dropdown.

But if u r asking for : add Text as option in dropdown , then ,

Working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FkA4/57/)

```
$('#categoryInputAddBtn').click(function () {
   var myDiv = $('#categoryInput').val();
    //this.append(myDiv); 
    var option = $('<option/>');
    option.attr({ 'value': 'myValue' }).text(myDiv);
    $('#platypusDropDown').append(option);
});
```

Comment: That is not what he was asking for. The question was about positioning, not about functionallity.

Comment: I already said , Check 3 lines . Then see `But if u r asking for : add Text as option in dropdown , then ,`  , please read answer properly

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with standard HTML select/option tags. But there are several different libraries emulating dropdown functionality and giving additional functionalities. One of those is [UI Kit](http://www.getuikit.com/index.html) which provides this among a lot of other features. You can add so called 'Grid' components to the dropdown which can in fact contain anything you want. See detail over [here](http://www.getuikit.com/docs/dropdown.html) under the headline 'Grid'.

Answer (score 0):

You can add input value to dropdown list.

```
var $platypusDropDown = $('#platypusDropDown');

$('#categoryInputAddBtn').on('click', function() {
  // Value of div input
  var $category = $('#categoryInput').val();

  // Add to dropdown list
  $platypusDropDown.append('<option value="' + $category + '">' + $category + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: He say I *don't* need to add div into the proper dropdownlist controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why you whant add div to Options? You could try like this:

```
$('#platypusDropDown').click(function () {
    var dropHeight = $(this.options[0]).height() * this.options.length;

    if($(this).data('open')) {
        $(this).data('open', false);
        $('#addCategory').css('padding-top', '0px')
        return;
    }   

    $('#addCategory').css('padding-top', dropHeight + 'px')
    $(this).data('open', true);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HwpG5/1/)